# ColdFusion 8 CFGRID - Headers not aligned with columns

Tags: coldfusion

CF8 - I have a CFGRID of type HTML where there are 5 data columns and the headers progressively are off from the data column..the first one lines up, the second one is off by about 2 px to the left of the data, the third one is off by about 4 px, the fifth one is off by about 6 px...cannot get the headers to sit exactly over the columns..if I pull the size of the column, the header still stays offset.

any ideas on why the column headers are offset?? I was thinking it might be css related but cannot find anything that looks like it might be affecting it..

Comment: Have u tried a different browser?  Have you removed all your custom CSS?  Is your browser text size set to Normal?

Comment: ok..it IS something in the css..running it outside of the control of the application.cfm, they line up...no clue WHERE it is in the css that is messing up yet though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Firebug Addon to Firefox. Activate it, point to headers text, look at css properties, probably it's padding or margin in file different than CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/ext/css/ext-all.css .

Comment: installed firefox - its not an approved browser for our company...:(

installed firebug...can see that the styling that is causing problems is likely the <td>..but I don't see how I can change it for just the cfgrid...(ext.js builds the grid as a table)...if I put some override styling before the cfgrid, it affects the whole page which is definately not going to be acceptable..

Comment: It turned out to be a padding: 2px in the td styling that was getting applied after the styling from the ext-all.css..was able to remove from my main css and nothing looks too strange, and the cfgrid header is fixed..so its good to go..
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> CF 10:
>   c:/Coldfusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/cfide/scripts/ajax/resources/ext/css/ext-all.css
>
> CF 9: d:/wwwroot/cfide/script/ajax/resources/ext/css/ext-all.css

This had to be commented out:

```
.x-grid3 table {
   table-layout:fixed;
}
```